# Flask+SQLAlchemy: How to show the latest entry in 1-to-many database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

Sorry I couldn't come up with a clear title, I'm not exactly sure what it is called that I want to accomplish. Also english is not my first language so please bear with me.

I've set up a database with two tables "Sensors" and "SensorValues".
There should be a one-to-many relationship so that one sensor can have many readings but the readings can belong to only one sensor.

I'm using Flask and flask-sqlalchemy.

Database models:

```
class Sensor(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name  = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, nullable=False,)
    gpiopin  = db.Column(db.INT, unique=False, nullable=False,)
    stype  = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False,)
    values = db.relationship('SensorValues', backref='author', lazy=True) #not a column in table, just backreference
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Sensor('{self.name}', '{self.gpiopin}', '{self.stype}')"

class SensorValues(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    reading = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=False)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, unique=False, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    sensor_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('sensor.id'), nullable=False)
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Value('{self.reading}', '{self.timestamp}')"
```

Here's the flask route for home.html:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
  sensors = Sensor.query.all()
  posts = SensorValues.query.all()
  return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, sensors=sensors, db=db)
```

How I generate the table in home.html

```
  <tbody>
            {% for sensor in sensors %}
                <tr>
                <td>{{ sensor.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ sensor.gpiopin }}</td>
                <td>{{ sensor.stype }}</td>
                <td>{{ sensor.values.reading }}</td> <- Where I want the latest reading of the specific sensor in the SensorValues to appear
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
```

Now, I have another table which lists all the readings and the names of the sensors they belong to.
It's basically a history and this way it works because I'm looping the SensorValues table directly.

```
  {% for post in posts %}
                <tr>
                <td>{{ post.author.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.author.stype }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.reading }}</td>
                <td>{{ post.timestamp }}</td>
                </tr>
  {% endfor %}
```

I tried to change the first loop to this:

```
{% for sensor in sensors %}
                <tr>
                <td>{{ sensor.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ sensor.gpiopin }}</td>
                <td>{{ sensor.stype }}</td>
                {{ lastvalue = SensorValues.filter_by(sensor_id=sensor.id).last()}}
                <td>{{ lastvalue.reading }}</td>
                </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Where I tried to make a filter query to the SensorValues table with the current sensor.id (the id of the Sensor the for loop is currently in) and logically I think that could work but the syntax is not correct. I got the Jinja error:

```
expected token 'end of print statement', got '='
```

Can I even do the query in the home.html or do I have to do it in the routes before the page is rendered?

Answer (score 1):

The query in the view function needs to be updated to include information about the latest reading for the sensors before passing it in the template context.

Start out with writing the query in SQL and then convert it to its SQLAlchemy variant.

The SQL query to find the last sensor reading values is the following:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5fXZyPiPYawc22ffMi2tYk/0

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT 
    s.*, 
    FIRST_VALUE(sv.reading) OVER (
  PARTITION BY sv.sensor_id ORDER BY sv.timestamp DESC
) AS last_reading
FROM sensors AS s
JOIN sensor_values AS sv ON s.id = sv.sensor_id
```

Now, let's build the SQLAlchemy variant

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa

sensors = Sensor.query.join(
              SensorValues).with_entities(
                  Sensor,
                      sa.func.first_value(
                          SensorValues.reading).over(
                              partition_by=SensorValues.sensor_id,
                              order_by=SensorValues.timestamp.desc
                          ).label('latest_reading'))
```

The Result rows returned from the above query are instances of [`KeyTuple`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict) and the `latest_reading` label should be available as a direct attribute of the sensor in the `Jinja2` template.

```html
{% for sensor in sensors %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ sensor.Sensor.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ sensor.Sensor.gpiopin }}</td>
        <td>{{ sensor.Sensor.stype }}</td>
        <td>{{ sensor.latest_reading }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I double-checked the method in my answer below and seems to work only once. I tried your code and it returns an error: 
File "/home/pi/app/app.py", line 54, in home
sa.func.first_value(
"NameError: name 'sa' is not defined"

Comment: Add this line in your imports `import sqlalchemy as sa`

Comment: type object 'SQLAlchemy' has no attribute 'func'?

Comment: I'm using flask-sqlalchemy, not SQLalchemy so do I need to install SQLalchemy too or can I just from flask-sqlalchemy import SQLalchemy as sa?

Comment: `flask-sqlalchemy` depends on the `sqlalchemy` package, so you're fine importing the package directly as in my previous comment. See how I have imported it in the SQLAlchemy variant of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I should edit this to the original post rather than posting it as an answer?

But anyways I got it working with:

```
     {% for sensor in sensors %}
            <tr>
            <td>{{ sensor.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ sensor.gpiopin }}</td>
            <td>{{ sensor.stype }}</td>
            {% set lastvalue = SensorValues.query.filter_by(sensor_id=sensor.id).order_by(SensorValues.timestamp.desc()).first() %}
            <td>{{ lastvalue.reading }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

And of course I had to add SensorValues to the route:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():
  sensors = Sensor.query.all()
  posts = SensorValues.query.all()
  #lastvalue = SensorValues.query.filter_by(sensor_id=sensor.id).last()
  return render_template('home.html', posts=posts, sensors=sensors, db=db, SensorValues=SensorValues
```

If there is a better way by all means show it, but for now it works.